# Non-admin user can't reserve survey respondents without getting error "Missing Interviewer contact."

Tags: error, permissions, civisurvey

WordPress 4.9.10
CiviCRM 4.7.29

When I'm logged into CiviCRM as an admin, the process of reserving respondents for a survey works fine.  However, if I'm logged in with a WP "Contributor" role (which is the role all my civicrm users have) I get an error message when I try to reserve them, "Missing Interviewer contact.", as seen below.

[image: When signed in as a "Contributor"]

Looking at the search criteria I see that there is no field to assign the interviewer as there is when I'm logged in as an admin:

[image: when signed in as an admin]

I checked my survey-related permissions and I think I have it setup correctly so a person with the "contributor" role should be able to do this:

[image]
[image]

Is there something else permissions-related that I need to be setting, or is this maybe a bug?

Thanks for any help,

Ruth

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need the "CiviCRM: access contact reference field" permission, based on what you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Just checked that and yes, I already have that checked on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd need to do 'Administer CiviCampaign' to get it going. What I did was enable that for the user group and then hid the admin stuff from the contributor role for editing the navigational menu